# I've cleared the cache at Netbean but Tomcat is still reading past projects

Tags: tomcat

I tried various way to clear away the "memory" in netbean but whenever I debug it's still resulted in netbean reading past projects thus giving me the error cos I do not think that there's anything wrong with my codes since I've checked through thoroughly and it worked perfectly well in the past.

I've deleted the entire cache folder in my netbean folder but it's still come back.

And restart plus clean the pertinent files many times but still not resolving the problem

I believe it's deeply rooted onto the Catalina in Tomcat.

If I'm right, how should I go about cleaning the embedded history at Catalina in Tomcat?

Hope to hear some advice. tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way out by remove the Tomcat and re-installing a new one and this sort of resolved the problem. No more reading the past history. :)